# nativescript-android: callback of "request location permissions on runtime"

Tags: android, callback, permissions, location, nativescript

So I am asking an android phone for a permission to use its location. I get the dialog box with deny or allow, which is fine. 
The problem is I don't know how to catch the response of that. My code is as follows:

```
var location_permissions = [ 
        (android as any).Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        (android as any).Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    ];

(android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat as any).requestPermissions( 
    app.android.foregroundActivity,
    location_permissions,
    "PERMISSION_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE"
);

// var grantResults = [];

// (app.android.foregroundActivity as any).onRequestPermissionsResult(
//     app.android.foregroundActivity,
//     "PERMISSION_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE",
//     location_permissions,
//     grantResults
// );
```

There is a documentation about using `onRequestPermissionsResult` which works as a callback, I guess? (https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) I wrote it there, but not sure how it should be implemented corectly. Since this is being written in angular2 with typescript, I thought I could catch the response with `.then`, but it throws an error: `cannot read property then of undefined`

Comment: Hi Starwave, NativeScript has external plugin called `nativescritp-geolocation` that provides such a functionality. Further more with the plugin you could also take the needed permissions by calling one method `enableLocationRequest(true);` - https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation/blob/master/source/location-monitor.d.ts#L39

Comment: I am already using it, but I need to know how to do this with android platform declarations like stated above, so I could bind other permissions as well, like calendar or read files or whatever...

Comment: You could use `nativescript-permissions` to request more permissions  or to use plugins code as example - https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-permissions/blob/master/permissions.android.js#L118-L179

Comment: I don't like using a plugin which supports only 1 platform. But thank you for pointing me in the right direction - I just checked geolocations code to see how they managed the permissions. Did the same manually in my code and it works, gona update the post later.

Comment: That plugin is for both platforms only that as you had example for android Nikolay put link to android part as example for yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked that plugins code and got from it what I wanted:

```
var location_permissions = [ 
        (android as any).Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION // no need to define "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION", because "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" includes permissions to NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER
    ];

var activityRequestPermissionsHandler_location = function (data) {
    //console.log('requestCode: ' + data.requestCode + ' permissions: ' + data.permissions + ' grantResults: ' + data.grantResults);
    if (data.requestCode === 1 ) {
        if (data.grantResults.length > 0 && data.grantResults[0] == android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            console.log("permission granted!!!");
        }
        else {
            console.log("permission not granted!!!");
        }
    }
    app.android.off(app.AndroidApplication.activityRequestPermissionsEvent, activityRequestPermissionsHandler_location);
};
app.android.on(app.AndroidApplication.activityRequestPermissionsEvent, activityRequestPermissionsHandler_location);

(android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat as any).requestPermissions( 
    app.android.foregroundActivity,
    location_permissions,
    1
);
```